# How to count a streak in Excel (Calc), with a changing range

Tags: excel, libreoffice-calc

I am creating a spreadsheet to track my habits through the coming year, and I want to be able to show both a simple count, and also a current streak for each habit. I've already searched and found one answer for counting a streak, but this answer does not work with a live tracker (increasing the end column by one each day), and also requires there to be no blank fields (1 or 0 entry).

```
=COUNTA(S$2:S$74)-MATCH(2, 1/(S2:S$74=0), 1)
```

If I switch the above from =0 to ="" in the match, it breaks pretty spectacularly, and in any case it fails completely for a range that includes 366 days, but the current day is <366. I would be tracking "current day" by a habit row labeled "logging" that I would populate each day, whether any other habits were logged or not. Is this something possible with formulas?

Using the suggestions I got to concat 1's and 0's to a string, I then got a successful streak formula using

```
=IFERROR((LEN(NG3)-SEARCH("0[^0]*$",NG3)),LEN(NG3))
```

Where NG is the column the concatenations exist in, and row 3 is the first row of data.
I then basically duplicated my calendar to allow for non-binary logging (converting any blank or 0 entry to a 0, all other entries to a 1), and contingent on the "logged" row being populated so that unlogged days are blank fields. Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation of the algorithm for this:

1. If you had a 1 for each time same thing happened, and 0 when you did something different.
2. Then you concatenated all the 0 and 1 into one long string.
3. Then split the string into an array based on 0, removing all the zeros.
4. Then finally counted the maximum length of the array result

In formula put the following:

```
=MAX(LEN(SPLIT(B1,"0")))
```

- Then either press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> on Windows
- Or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> on a Mac

This will convert formula into an *ArrayFormula*.

(You need to do this, because if you just entered

```
=SPLIT(B1)
```

in **C1**, it would generate a range of columns, one per array entry, filling C1, D1, E1 etc...).

Here are the formulae:

[image: Array Formula Example]

Here is the output:

[image: Output from Formula]

Sample spreadsheet in [GoogleDocs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Uex05M6d4NInnmjAh0abo5CCFTISaSfZbrtVWzItPBQ/edit?usp=sharing)

You may be able to upload/download/convert it between Googledocs and LibreOffice.

Have not used that spreadsheet solution.

But most are pretty similar these days.

Comment: Doesn't quite work as-is, but you pointed me in the right direction. Using the idea to concat 1's and 0's into a string, I finally settled on the following formula for a streak that seems to work in all situations
```
=IFERROR((LEN(NG3)-SEARCH("0[^0]*$",NG3)),LEN(NG3))
```